# Как программно узнать какой рингтон звучит во время входящего звонка?

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте все.
Есть приложение, которое перехватывает момент входящего звонка и пишет в лог-файл его параметры.
Удалось узнать номер входящего звонка и запись в телефонной книге, соответствующую этому номеру. В частности, назначен ли контакту собственный рингтон и получить его параметры. У рингтона есть метод isPlaying(). Но во всех случаях я получаю false для любого рингтона.
Вопрос: как правильно определить какой рингтон реально звучит во время входящего звонка?

```
String customRingtone = cursor.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE));
Uri customRingtoneUri = Uri.parse(customRingtone);
Ringtone r = rm.getRingtone(context, customRingtoneUri);
String ringtoneIsPlayng = String.valueOf(r.isPlaying());
```